# Масштабирование изображения по высоте и ширине

Tags: css, изображения, img

Подскажите пожалуйста, как средствами css решить следующее:

Есть блок, ширина которого `width: calc(100% - 288px)`, а высота соответствует высоте экрана. Внутри него изображение. Задача — масштабировать это изображение пропорционально, как часто используется в слайд-шоу. Например, как здесь https://madebyminimal.com/demo/milo/#ms-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .main {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
 }
        
 .main a img {
     display: block;
     margin: auto;
     max-height: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]